# DTOs validation is not happening

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, dto

I am new to nest js and trying to write a generic crud service and controller using Mixin that provides basic crud api support to consumers extending it. I have used the global validation pipe and have defined the dtos but the validation is not happening for post request.

Here is my code:

crud.controller.ts

```
import {
  Get,
  Param,
  Post,
  Body,
  Delete,
  Query,
  Patch,
  Injectable,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { GetPaginationQuery, Pagination } from '../pagination';
import { CrudEntity, ICrudService } from './crud.interface';

export function CrudControllerMixin<
  Entity extends CrudEntity,
  CreateDto,
  UpdateDto,
>() {
  @Injectable()
  class CrudController {
    constructor(
      public readonly crudService: ICrudService<Entity, CreateDto, UpdateDto>,
    ) {}

    @Get()
    findAll(@Query() params: GetPaginationQuery): Promise<Pagination<Entity>> {
      return this.crudService.getAll(params);
    }

    @Get(':id')
    findOne(@Param('id') id: number): Promise<Entity | null> {
      return this.crudService.getOne(+id);
    }

    @Post()
    create(@Body() body: CreateDto): Promise<Entity | null> {
      return this.crudService.create(body);
    }

    @Patch(':id')
    update(
      @Param('id') id: number,
      @Body() body: UpdateDto,
    ): Promise<Entity | null> {
      return this.crudService.update(+id, body);
    }

    @Delete(':id')
    async remove(id: number): Promise<void> {
      return this.crudService.remove(id);
    }
  }

  return CrudController;
}
```

persona.controller.ts

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreatePersonaDto } from './dto/create-persona.dto';
import { UpdatePersonaDto } from './dto/update-persona.dto';
import { CrudControllerMixin } from 'src/common/crud';
import { Persona } from './entities/persona.entity';
import { PersonasService } from './personas.service';

@Controller('personas')
export class PersonasController extends CrudControllerMixin<
  Persona,
  CreatePersonaDto,
  UpdatePersonaDto
>() {
  constructor(private readonly personasService: PersonasService) {
    super(personasService);
  }
}
```

Create dto

```
    import { IsNotEmpty, IsString, MaxLength } from 'class-validator';

export class CreatePersonaDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @MaxLength(5, { message: 'Name must be within 5 characters' })
  persona_name: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @MaxLength(25, { message: 'Label must be within 25 characters' })
  persona_label: string;
}
```

Comment: Have you added `new ValidationPipe` into `app.useGlobalPipes`?

Comment: In crul.controller I don't see you using CreatePersonaDto, is any mistake in there?

Comment: Yes i have added the validation pipe globally.

// in main.ts i have
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, transform: true }));

Comment: @HaiAlison I have passed the CreatePersonaDto to CrudControllerMixin and used that to validate in the create method. But the validation is not throwing errors when i give invalid inputs

Comment: I think you should remove the `whitelist: true` , it worked for me but I don't understand how it works :D

Comment: @HaiAlison Removed but still not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the @Controller decorator to define the controller, if yes, make sure to add the following decorator to the controller class:

`@Controllers(AssignValidationOptions.Factory).`

This will use the NestJS AssignValidationOptions service provider to handle your validation automatically, but if you need more manual control of the validation, you can remove the decorator to disable automatic validation, and manage the validation of individual fields via the @AssignValidationOptions metadata.

Comment: Sry i am not getting it. Can you pls provide a sample code.

Comment: add this to your DTO:

```export const createDtoValidation = Joi.object(
  new CreateDto(),
);
```
and add this line before your @Post()
 ```@UsePipes(
    new JoiValidationPipe({
      body: createDtoValidation,
    }),
  )```